# Select date,sum(volume) from IO where code like '%C%' group by date, how to implment in pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

in Shell, use following code

```
    db.IO.aggregate([  
    {$match :{ code:/C/}},                                           
    {$group : { _id : "$date", dailyvolume:{$sum:"$volume"}}}
    ])
```

Result:

```
    {
    "result" : [ 
    {
    "_id" : "20140718",
    "dailyvolume" : 80706
     }, 
     ...
```

But in pymongo,

```
    posts.aggregate([
    {'$match' :{ 'code':'/C/'}},                          
    {"$group" : { "_id" : "$date", "dailyvolume" : { "$sum" : "$volume" } }}
    ])
```

Result:

```
    {u'ok': 1.0, u'result': []}
```

How to fix it in pymongo to get the same result as Shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex needs not to be a string, so either use python's regular expression built in:

```js
regex = re.compile("C")
posts.aggregate([
    { "$match" :{ "code": regex} },                          
    { "$group" : { "_id" : "$date", "dailyvolume" : { "$sum" : "$volume" } }}
])
```

Or use the [**`$regex`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) query literal:

```js
posts.aggregate([
    { "$match" :{ "code": { "$regex": "C" } }},                          
    { "$group" : { "_id" : "$date", "dailyvolume" : { "$sum" : "$volume" } }}
])
```